# SQL table structure for questions/answer system?

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a question posting system. Each question post must contain the Users ID/username and the unique question id

**MY TABLES**

```
------------USERS---------------------------------
  id 
  uname 
  password 
  fname 
  lname 

-----------QUESTIONS-----------------------------

user_id
question_id
question
description
time
```

I am a beginner here, please put up with me. I just don't know how I can match my users_ID with question id as they are on separate tables.That way when a question is posted I can retrieve the users ID who posted the question alongside with the question id.

My rationality with combining the tables will not work simply because I can't think of a way to match a users unique id with the question_id. Please help me...really lost

Comment: Do you mean [like this](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/271661)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Inner Join` to display the matched records in between the two tables:

```
SELECT 
      question_id,
      question,
      id,
      uname
FROM Questions A INNER JOIN Users B
     ON A.user_id=B.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show up your question data with an user_id, it associated with user and question table. you can use `inner join` like this.

For show up your question data :

```
select * from questions inner join user on question.user_id=user.id;
```